# Who's the one making the HTTP request in this ASP.net code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Title states the question.

```
doc.Load("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=468739&u=c");
//parsing code goes here
```

I'm positive that it's the server that does the request, loads the document and parses it as opposite to the client using the page. However, a coworker says the contrary. We need to know this due to proxy authentication issues.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Simple rule of thumb: if it's in your code-behind / aspx page, it's on your end; if it's through javascript, it's on their end.

Comment: Yep, been there done that (proxy issues with mapping APIs - Bing and Google - that worked fine with client requests). Just out of curiosity, what made your co-worker think the client was making the request?

Comment: My co-worker thought that since the .aspx was on a html iframe then the client should have been doing the request (I told him it was silly but he didn't listen). THANKS A LOT EVERYONE FOR THE FAST ANSWERS!

Comment: `XmlDocument.Load()` is that you?!!  If not, which Load() exactly are we talking about?  (Note: I guess you're not yahooapis.com, so your server probably is playing client to another server)  I think we'd all expect to see `window.open()` if it was in client side code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WHO execute the code? Your ASP.NET page hosted on the server? Then it's the SERVER!

If you were executing the code is Silverlight or something like that, it will the client.